# Verification regarding Neumann conditions at time derivative (1 Viewer)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

just a question regarding neumann conditions, I seem to have forgotten these things already. I think this question is answerable by a yes or a no.

So given the 2D heat equation,

$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha  \left [\frac{\partial T^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial T^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}   \right ]
$$

If I assign a neumann condition at say, x = 0;

$$
\left.\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}
\end{matrix}\right|_{x=0}=k
$$

1. Does it still follow that at both $T(x,y,t)$ and $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$, the condition holds?
2. Does this follow that everytime, the correct value of $\frac{\partial T^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial T^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}$ at $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ follows the condition $\left.\begin{matrix}
   \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}
   \end{matrix}\right|_{x=0}=k$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your 1st question. The governing PDE is constrained by the boundary condition, if that's what you mean by "does it follow the BC".

Comment: I was pertaining to the boundary. Say there are nodes on the boundary along x = 0, are they governed by both:
d²T/dx² + d²T/dy² and
dT/dx |[x =0]  = k 

at all T and dT/dt.

Comment: Yes, the PDE is satisfied throughout the domain and including the boundaries. The initial condition may not always be consistent with the boundary condition leading to a discontinuity, so that at time $t=0$, the temperature at a portion of the boundary may not be equal to the specified initial condition, and this will be reflected in the breakdown of the solution at very short times from the startup. You see this all the time in $1$-D transient heat transfer problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have one last question, though; just for clarification.

Does this mean that at the boundary x = 0, the PDE is governed by dT/dt = d²T/dx² + d²T/dy², but the quantity dT/dx at each node is held at 0, and not dT/dt = (0 - dT/dx)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, but in order for this to hold, your initial and boundary conditions must be consistent.